# create-react-app is not working since version 4.0.1

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-install, npx

I tried installing `create-react-app` using `npm i create-react-app`, `npx create-react-app new-app` and `npm init react-app new-app`, but I keep getting this error message:

> You are running create-react-app 4.0.0, which is behind the latest
> release (4.0.1). We no longer support global installation of Create
> React App.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 240):

This worked for me:

```
npx create-react-app@latest your-project-name --use-npm
```

Answer (score 148):

[According to the `create-react-app` docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started#quick-start), `create-react-app` should ***not*** be installed globally:

> If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, we recommend you uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` or `yarn global remove create-react-app` to ensure that `npx` always uses the latest version.

This is even stated in the error message you recieved:

> You are running create-react-app 4.0.0, which is behind the latest release (4.0.1).
> **We no longer support global installation of Create React App.**

You must uninstall `create-react-app` with `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`.

Then each time you want to create a new React app with `create-react-app`, use the command **`npx create-react-app my-app`**.

So to fix the error you're getting, uninstall `create-react-app` globally, update npm, clear the cache, and retry creating the app.

Run this in your terminal:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app && npm i -g npm@latest && npm cache clean -f && npx create-react-app@latest my-app --use-npm
```

Comment: `clear the cache` is the important piece i was missing thanks

Answer (score 34):

I got

```
You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.
```

so I simply called the package with an explicit version:

```
npx create-react-app@5.0.0 app-name
```

Comment: If anyone is still facing that problem after uninstalling it globally and cleaning the cache, try to run `npm uninstall create-react-app` as you might have a non-global installation.

Comment: Using an explicit version after uninstalling globally and clearing the cache solved the problem for me

Answer (score 27):

I also faced this issue after they released v4.0.2.

They have mentioned this:

> If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, we recommend you uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` or `yarn global remove create-react-app` to ensure that `npx` always uses the latest version.

I resolved the issue by following the below steps:

1. Uninstall `create-react-app` v4.0.1:

   ```sh
   # for npm:
   npm uninstall -g create-react-app

   # for yarn:
   yarn global remove create-react-app
   ```
2. You are not required to install `create-react-app` in your local directory, so if you do not want to do this then move to step 3. If you want to do this, install v4.0.2 **without** using the global flag (`-g` or `--global`) using the below command:

   ```sh
   # for npm:
   npm i create-react-app

   # for yarn:
   yarn add create-react-app
   ```
3. You can now create a new React app using the below command:

   ```sh
   # for npx:
   npx create-react-app my-app

   # for npm:
   npm init react-app my-app

   # for yarn:
   yarn create react-app my-app
   ```

Comment: This works....it's important to note, if you use both npm and yarn for different reasons you may run into a situation where you try to uninstall create-react-app with the wrong package manager (not the one you installed it with). In that case, try both the npm and yarn uninstall command....one of them should work

Answer (score 16):

I also face the same problem but the problem gets solved when I uninstall the `create-react-app` globally and then again install it globally.

Uninstalling Command:

> `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

installing Command:

> `npx create-react-app my-app`

if you have an older npm version (npm version < 5.2) then use this command :

> `npm install -g create-react-app`

it solved my problem I hope it will solve yours

Comment: This answer is incorrect: [`create-react-app` should **not** be installed globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65043610/12860895)

Answer (score 10):

Updating NPX worked for me. Suggestions on this page didn't do the trick but might have contributed.

```
npm update npx
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me! It's amazing how many errors can be resolved simply updating/reinstalling packages.

Answer (score 9):

```
 npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Although the uninstall command ran successfully , it was not able to uninstall create-react-app, so i kept running into the same error again and again

This finally worked for me `npx create-react-app@latest my-app --template typescript`

Comment: For me uninstall did not work it, was the @latest that kicked this going. Thx :)

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me was:

```sh
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

And then:

```sh
npm i create-react-app # or yarn add create-react-app
```

I also updated the Node version.

Answer (score 8):

Uninstalling create-react-app globally via npm and reinstalling without the global flag did not work for me.

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm install create-react-app
```

I was on node version 15.2.0. I upgraded to the latest stable node version 15.3.0 via nvm.

```
nvm install node
```

Then I installed create-react-app again (no global flag).

```
npm install create-react-app
```

I was then able to successfully create a new react app.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

EDIT: The above will install create-react-app to your current directory. To be clear, after uninstalling create-react-app globally I was no longer able to create an app via npx and received the same original error message. The best solution I've found so far is to run `npm install -g npm@latest` which downgraded my npm version from 7.0.14 dev build to 6.14.9 LTS build and allowed me to create the react app via npx without issue.

Comment: `npm install create-react-app` outside of an npm project doesn't do anything. Just running `npx create-react-app my-app` will create a new React app.

Comment: @ΛRYΛN Running 'npx create-react-app my-app' after uninstalling globally threw the same error as the original post. This did not work. Installing create-react-app without the global flag installed it to my current directory which allowed me to create a new react app but you're correct maybe it's not the best approach. I've found a better way and updated my post above but I'm still trying to figure out where exactly create-react-app is installed if not globally. I don't see it in any of the expect locations, mainly /Users/{username}/.nvm/versions/node/v15.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules.

Answer (score 6):

After `create-react-app > 4.0.1` use these commands

### npm

```sh
npm init react-app my-app
```

### yarn

```sh
yarn create react-app my-app
```

---

[Getting Started | Create React App Docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)

Answer (score 5):

I have nvm installed, and while using the command `npx create-react-app my-app`; I got this error:

```
You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.1, which is behind the latest release (4.0.2).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app
```

I confirmed that I did not have create-react-app installed globally in my nvm global directory.

I solved issue by specifying the version of the package

```
npx create-react-app@4.0.2 my-app
```

Comment: I had the same problem, peeked into my `~/.npm/_npx` and found the directory with 4.0.1, when providing the version and creating my react app, npx created the 4.0.2 as well. I wonder if this is a problem with npx not being able to clean it's cache or just being confused?!

Answer (score 5):

For me it was the issue with my npm version. So i did this:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Now `npx create-react-app app_name` works.

Answer (score 4):

I had to downgrade to the latest stable version of node with n in order to make it work.

```
sudo n stable
```

Just to make it clear, I never installed it globally, I just had this problem after upgrading node.

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm late to the party, but here are my two cents to help you. This is how I made it worked

**Uninstall Global create-react-app installation**

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

**Now clear the npx cache by**

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

Now try to create the application; if you still get the error saying we don't support create-react-app, **change the directory to create the application**

run

```
 npx create-react-app my-app
```

This is how I made this worked

Answer (score 3):

There are two different causes of this error:

1. You have create-react-app installed globally. Use this command to find out if you do: `npm list -g --depth 0`. If so, follow the instructions in the error message to uninstall it globally.
2. You are using node v15.0.0+. Use NVM to switch to the LTS `nvm use --lts` and then run create-react-app. After that you can switch to v15.0.0+ and continue working. (If you do not have NVM installed, here is how you can install it: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: #2 worked for me. I knew that I had not ever installed `create-react-app` globally and was confused by all the posts and documentation assuming that users _did_ install it globally. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have it installed globally and I'm using node `14.15.4`, so there is another cause for it. I have yet to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

For me I got the same error even though `create-react-app` was installed in a parent directory, not globally. So I ran `npm uninstall create-react-app` without the `-g` flag and it worked.

Comment: @Can we use this approach?  I am a beginner and not very sure if this will cause any issues in the future?

Comment: First off, when you uninstall a package you can always undo what you did by reinstalling. You would do this by running in the root of the directory that the  package was deleted from- `npm install create-react-app` or if you want to reinstall the a specific version  `npm install create-react-app@1.2.0`. But I don't think you would need to do that because as I understand it the idea is to use npx which as I understand it doesn't download any packages but uses the package hosted on on the npm registry. So you don't need the `create-react-app` package on your computer at all to use the package.

Comment: When you run `npx create-react-app new-app` you're saying "Hey npm server, please use the create react package on your server to help me create a react app."

Answer (score 3):

**Using Git Bash on Windows i run into the same issue today**

```
npx create-react-app appname
```

even didn't worked after i uninstalled the global installation with

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

**What solved the problem for me was to clean the npm cache with the following command**

```
npm cache clean -f
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
sudo npm uninstall create-react-app -g

sudo npm install create-react-app@5.0.0 -g

npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution-1: Update your node package manager by using the command below.

```
npm install -g npm@latest
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Solution-2: Run your PowerShell as administrator and run the commands. Something this will not work

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm install -g create-react-app
//OR
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Solution-3: The permanent solution is to uninstall  **node.js** and **NPM** and install them once again.

*enjoy*

Answer (score 2):

i was facing same issues a while ago

```
npx create-react-app@latest app-name
```

worked for me

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me after updating NodeJS to version 16.

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
npm install create-react-app
```

Comment: `npm install create-react-app` outside of an npm project doesn't do anything. Just running `npx create-react-app my-app` will create a new React app.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this myself today and my root cause is likely very rare but perhaps it will help someone else.

I had an npm registry defined in my `.npmrc` which my work requires us to use. Turns out my work mirror didn't have `4.0.1` and something in `create-react-app` must phone home and run a version check.

If you have a registry defined run `npm view create-react-app` to check the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

After exploring the Github issues a bit I found a solution to this problem that was posted, which doesnt require downgrading node or npm.

I'm using Ubuntu on WSL2 so keep in mind locations might vary.  The problem comes from npm having cached a global installation of create-react-app with npx that is v4.0.0 which doesnt show when you use `npm view create-react-app`.

If you find your npm cache which for me was located in `~/.npm/_npx/` folder, you will find folders with hashed names from all your global installs where you have used npx previously.

If you look through each of them for example with `cat [hash]/package.json` and note down the hash of any that contains create-react-app.  Now go ahead and manually edit the package.json files to bump the version of create-react-app to `4.0.1` - and afterwards remove it from node modules with `rm -rf [hash]/node_modules/create-react-app`.

After this if you go back out and try to run `npx create-react-app my-app` it will prompt you to install 'create-react-app' as normal and should work fine, and now npx will have cached the correct version of 'create-react-app' so you wont have the issue again either.  And you can use whichever version of node and npm you like.

If you're on Windows or Mac you have to figure out where the cache is located, as I don't know - but the rest of the steps should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

i didn't have any global create-react-app i just did `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and then i did `npm install create-react-app`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and the error isn't quite as explanatory as it should be. I fixed it by updating npx itself.

Please type in `npm update npx`in your terminal to resolve the problem.

After that you can type in `npx create-react-app "your preferred project name"` to create your react project.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me.

I tried the commands listed in a previous answer. I ran them one by one instead of running them as linked commands in case any of them failed. But I got to the create-react-app command and it failed.

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app && npm i -g npm@latest && npm cache clean -f && npx create-react-app my-app
```

I don't know why, but even after I updated npm and uninstalled globally and cleared the cache, it wouldn't work until I ran

```
npm i create-react-app
```

Note: I installed create-react-app without the -g flag. Because as noted by others in this thread, installing create-react-app globally is no longer recommended. Although the other answers are better, if someone makes it to this answer that might be one more thing to take notice of and try.

Answer (score 1):

I've uninstalled create-react-app globally also from yarn

```
npm uninstall create-react-app -g
```

And the reinstalled create-react-app

```
npm i create-react-app
```

or another way is:

```
npm create-react-app@latest my-app
npm create-react-app@4.0.2 my-app
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers didn't work for me. Trying to uninstall globally, for instance, might work to uninstall it but the error persists. It persisted across new installations of Node, and so on.

However, the following seems straightforward and worked for me:

1. Go into some fresh folder, in which you'll create the app, so that it doesn't already know about create-react-app.
2. `yarn add create-react-app`
3. `yarn run create-react-app myapp`

Comment: Holy crap, after doing "yarn add create-react-app" "npx create-react-app" started working again!!! tnx

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

**Step # 1:** Remove globally the create-react-app package:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

**Step # 2:** Install again globally the create-react-app package:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

That will install the version 5.0.1 (or higher). To check if it was properly installed, run this on the terminal:

```
npm list -g
```

Result:

￼
[image: response on the terminal]

And then try again to create the react app, using the sentence:

```
npx create-react-app <project_name>
```

And then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by:

1. uninstalling node via terminal using home-brew.
2. Make sure to do a deep clean by using the following commands:

   ```
    brew uninstall node; 
    brew cleanup;
    brew uninstall --force node
   ```
3. Go to [node.js download link](https://nodejs.org/en/) and download the ***stable version*** package and install it. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best answer IMO. I also did a "brew search node" and then node@14 showed up as the latest stable version in brew. So then "brew install node@14" did the trick. One may also need to update the path, but brew will make it clear if needed: export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin:$PATH". Then everything works as expected.

Comment: I would highly recommend installing NVM as the solution would be as simple as switching to the LTS, running create-react-app and then switching back to the node version you were previously on.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

then

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Comment: You dont install globally. Read the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65043610/4826457

Comment: it worked for me too, but honestly, I don't know why it worked because I've installed it globally again

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled node.js and reinstalled it using windows installer. Now npx create-react-app command works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to start CMD as administrator and run the usual command:

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply updating node fixed this issue for me

Comment: There are more detailed answers to answer this question therefore this answer should be a comment instead.

Comment: Not enough reputations to add it as a comment yet

Answer (score 0):

After some time trying to fix this the issue is within Yarn. You have to run these scripts to fix this:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app

npm i -g yarn

npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with **create-react-app** but I had to take a quite different solution approach after trying almost all proposed solutions here...

##### When npx create-react-app stopped working:

After upgrading **nodejs** to version 16 on my machine (Windows 10), I kept getting the warning **create-react-app** version was 4.0.3, which was being the latest version 5.0.0 and that I had to run `npm uninstall global create-react-app` or `yarn remove global create-react-app` beacause npx on newer nodejs version already come with create-react-app built in... However, performing the commands above did nothing! I also executed `npm cache clean -f` and updated npm with `npm i -g npm@latest`, but still nothing!

#### Final Solution

Which definately worked for me though was to delete two files (**create-react-app.cmd** and **creat-react-app** bin file), propably related to create-react-app being installed globally with **yarn**! They were located on `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin` on my windows machine...

After performing the global uninstallation of created-react-app with npm and yarn, and then deleting the mentioned files, **`nxp create react-app my-app`** started working again!

I hope that help some of you guys too!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling by `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` or `yarn global remove create-react-app` didn't work for me.

- Neither did clearing cache with:
  `npx clear-npx-cache`
- Because `get-command create-react-app` still showed CRA present globally!

**My issue was using different version of Node in NVM:**

I had to uninstall CRA for every version of Node.js managed by NVM!

```
nvm list
nvm use [version]
npm uninstall -g create-react-app   (for every version in the list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're running an out-of-date version of NodeJS, because that's all your OS offers as a regular package? *That was the problem in my case*.

**TL/DR; the solution**: Install the snap version of NodeJS.

Ubuntu 20.04, for instance, currently ships NodeJS v.10.19.0, and I was seeing the exact same error as the original questioner (who didn't specify their OS).

In any case, for me the solution was to first remove the Node package:

```
$ sudo apt remove nodejs
```

And, since I already had the Snap environment set up (see https://snapcraft.io if you don't), I installed NodeJS v.16.17.1 using this command:

```
$ sudo snap install node --classic
```

If you're using another OS you'll need a different command (e.g. `yum`, or maybe `rpm`) to remove the old Node package. The snap command is probably the same for users of any recent OS, with the Snap system installed.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the npm fixed the issue for me - `npm i -g npm@latest`

Answer (score -1):

I had to upgrade to the latest stable version of node using nvm

```
nvm install [version.number]
nvm use [version.number]
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to switch to the a previous version of node, using the stable current one didn't work. I switched to 14.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting this error even with create-react-app uninstalled globally.
My npm and node versions were also fine.
What worked for me was to:

1. Install create-react-app locally (without `-g`)
2. Then, `npx create-react-app my-app` in that directory