# problem running create-react-app using npx

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

when I was trying to run create-react-app using the command `npx create-react-app app` I got the following Message

```
You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.1, which is behind the latest release (4.0.3).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

I then tried to uninstall create-react-app globally using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and rerun npx command again i still get the same message that I should uninstall create-react-app globally even so the only module that is installed globally is npm on my machine

Answer (score 1):

You first need to uninstall the globally installed `create-react-app` and then, invalidate the cache.

Command for the same: `npm uninstall -g create-react-app && npm cache clean -f`

Now, you may continue with creating the application again using: `npx create-react-app application-name`.

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963796/create-react-app-is-not-working-since-version-4-0-1/65043610).

Answer (score 0):

Try **npm cache clean –-force** command after uninstalling **create-react-app** globally.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, the following code will work:

npx create-react-app@latest my-app

Issue(#10601): https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10601