# yarn error while creating react application. Existing answer not helping

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I am getting below error while creating `react` app in my system.many times reinstalled `react` and even `nodejs`. Still issue is keep coming.

```
PS C:\Users\u124\Desktop\nsh-adm\learning\nestJS> npx create-react-app reactadmin
```

Error is

```
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\u124\Desktop\nsh-adm\learning\nestJS\reactadmin.\\

warning ..\package.json: No license field
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.15
warning ..\package.json: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react: unable to get local issuer certificate".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\u124\\Desktop\\nsh-adm\\learning\\nestJS\\reactadmin\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd C:\Users\u124\Desktop\nsh-adm\learning\nestJS\reactadmin has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.
PS C:\Users\u124\Desktop\nsh-adm\learning\nestJS>
```

Can you please help me on the same.

Comment: _"Existing answer not helping"_... what existing answer?

Comment: Have you previously installed `create-react-app` globally? I'm seeing [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65043610/283366) to uninstall it if so to ensure `npx` uses the latest version

Comment: Thank you Phil. the link you posted is really helpful. I also learnt some of the other things. issue resolved.

Comment: Yes I installed globally. I am newbie.

Comment: All good. Whatever you do, please ignore any advice around disabling SSL checks.

Comment: sure Phil..thank you so much.