# Problems while executing npx create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, installation

I created react projects on my pc before but now my npx create-react-app command is not working both on already existing projects as well as on new projects.
[this is my error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cASr8.png)

I applied this methods to solve but it failed: npm install, chache removal commands, installing create react app commands, uninstalled nodejs and installed again. but still I am getting this messages

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: Included in the image link. Please check again

Comment: There should notbe any space in folder name . Try `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: applied but message is same.

Comment: Try referring the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963796/create-react-app-is-not-working-since-version-4-0-1), it might help you.

Comment: @MayuriSKulkarni thanks for that link. But unfortunately I am getting same message

Comment: The website of npm i.e., "registry.npmjs.org" has now got multiple ip6 addresss while the operating systems firewall for example, in ubuntu 20.04 ufw is blocking ip6 addresses. This is the reason the users are getting error.