# Unable to use command : npx create-react-app <app-name> because of global installation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

Good evening, I'm trying to start a react projet using the classic `npx create-react-app <app-name>`, but I encounter the message :

```
You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app
```

So do I ! I run the next command as asked : `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`, immediatly it returns me a `up to date in 63ms`.

All seems good but if I try the create app command, it still send me the same error message ...

I tried with the yarn one too, same issue, I even uninstalled nodejs from my computer, reinstalled it, still same issue !

Running on windows.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Do you have git-bash or some other way of using standard Unix tools? `which npm-create-react-app` would tell you why `npm` thinks it's installed globally, and `file -h` on the result of that would tell you if that's actually a broken link, which you could just unlink or delete.

Or in CMD, you could use `where` instead of `which`, then go to that path in Explorer and see what kind of file it is.

Comment: I found this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963796/create-react-app-is-not-working-since-version-4-0-1?rq=2.

Comment: Yes i have a wsl2, I'll try this

Comment: I used `npx create-react-app@latest your-project-name --use-npm` and it works, fine for me, thanks you for help